# User session expired on HA proxy for HTTPS request

Tags: haproxy

I have configured HA proxy LB for two nodes for my application web service. I have setup SSL for all https request & for http requests without SSL.
I am using different ports http & https Where i have used http, the home page, log-in and accessing my app webservice pages all are works fine. 
When i tried for https web request, My application home page comes fine but when i tried to log-in, facing below issue (after increased timeout values.)

> User session expired. Please, log in again

&

> An error occured while communicating with server.

What i have to update on my /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file.

```
#### HTTPS ######

frontend https-in
        bind *:9443 ssl crt /etc/SSL1/Certs1/Combined.pem no-sslv3
        timeout client 60s
        option tcplog
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 9443
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        default_backend backend_servers_tomcat_https

backend backend_servers_tomcat_https
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout server 10s
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        server server01 server01.example.com:9443 check ssl verify none
        server server02 server02.example.com:9443 check ssl verify none
```

Comment: have you setup the `proxyName` and `proxyPort` in the tomcat config? [The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html) [Proxy Support How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Comment: @Aleksandar I have checked tomcat.properties and server.xml both are fine , is there any other things need to check/update respect with `HTTPS`